# How to test my website for basic sql injection vulnerabilities?

Tags: php, sql, mysqli, sql-injection

I'm creating a basic website with a login screen for a project and I want to test it for some basic sql injection vulnerabilities. I'm using a form to read a username and a password from a user and this line of  PHP code to find their info in my database and print it to them:

`if(isset($_POST['username'])&&$_POST['username']!=""&&isset($_POST['pass']      )&&$_POST['pass']!=""){
    $sql="SELECT username,pass,email,name,surname,ADT,tel,address,bdate,gender FROM myusers WHERE username='".$_POST['username']."' AND pass='".$_POST['pass']."'";}`

Thanks in advance for your help. If you need any additional info about my code, please ask.

Comment: I can tell you that your code is vulnerable right away, without any tests.

Comment: simple, just ask one question: "is there *any* statement whatsoever that is *not* completely parameterized?" - if the answer is yes, then yes, your code is **very vulnerable**. which is obvious in your example. just imagine someone posting a username `'; DROP TABLE myusers; --`.. by the way: **never ever ever! store plain text passwords!** use `password_hash()` and `password_verify()`! *(everytime you store a plain password, root moves a kitten to /dev/null)*

Answer (score 0):

I will suggest to use some fiddler(I recommend telerik fiddler) and manually create request. Via that program you can prepare your sql-injection request and see server response. Over here you have some basic examples:

```
0+1, 2-1, (...) - if it return specific record, your code is vulnerable
In your case check this:
x' or 'x'='x'         
x' or 'x'='x' -- 
1 AND 1=(SELECT 1), 1 AND 1=(SELECT 0) - check if subquery works
```

You can also check [cheat sheet](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/SQL_Injection_Prevention_Cheat_Sheet) and [sql injection cheat sheet](http://pentestmonkey.net/cheat-sheet/sql-injection/mysql-sql-injection-cheat-sheet).